# Can one create an MIQ Dev Appliance in Linux or Windows environment?

Tags: manageiq

[This README file](https://github.com/ManageIQ/manageiq-appliance-dev-setup) provides a link to instructions on how to create the ManageIQ Appliance dev setup for a MAC OSX environment, but it says that Linux instructions are TBD.  See Screenshot:

[image]

Are we truly limited to MAC OS for development?  Are there no instructions out there for setting up in a Linux or Windows environment?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can one create an MIQ Dev Appliance in Linux or Windows environment?

You can find the detailed guide [here](https://www.manageiq.org/docs/guides/developer_setup.html) for different Linux distros.

> Are we truly limited to MAC OS for development?

The main limitation is that Podman client On MacOS doesn't work properly. Since podman a tool for running Linux containers, you gonna need some remote linux machine running, in order to install the remote client and then setup ssh connection information in the podman-remote.conf file. ([here](https://podman.io/getting-started/installation))